# What's the Purpose of SQL Identity Specification

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Imagine I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Things](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT (newId()),
    [ThingName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ThingCode] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

It would be harder to support it if I made the **Id** column an **Identity**.
Is there any performance considerations or anything that make me change my mind?

Thanks,

Comment: it appears like the main point you're talking about is that guids are large. Assuming the fact that the system works in distributed environment and using GUID is a must, it's not a argument for me to consider.

Comment: Why would being an identity be harder to support?

Comment: Because of Identity Inserts and stuff like that. It's not a big deal though.

Comment: YOu shouldbn't be doing identity inserts in general

Answer (score 6):

Performance considerations: Yes. A [uniqueidentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) (GUID) column is fine as a Primary key, BUT not as the clustered index. Create the clustered index on column(s) that will be used in range searches, and create a non-clustered index on the GUID column.

A uniqueidentifier (GUID) column uses 16 bytes, so storage space used is higher (and less rows fit on a database page), and bandwidth consumed by data transfer is higher.

- [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx#ixzz1TC96o37H)

The main use for a GUID as a primary key (over an `int` or `bigint`) is the ability to assign these in the middle application tier without making a round trip to the database, while still avoiding key clashes.

If all you need is a key range larger than an int (4bytes, 2<sup>31</sup> - 1) then use a `bigint` (8 bytes), which supports 2<sup>63</sup> - 1 rows (more than enough for most applications)

Answer (score 2):

[uniqueidentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) is a *large* field, so you will be storing and moving more data around over the network - that's one performance consideration.

Additionally, [`newid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) (as far as I know) will **not** generate sequential identifiers, causing index fragmentation which is a major performance issue if you decide to use the column as a clustered index.

The main use for the type is in disconnected scenarios, where you need to generate the key and avoid clashes when reconnecting and adding new data.

Comment: "causing index fragmentation which is a major performance issue if you decide to use the column as a primary key" is incorrect. only clustering key on GUID causes a problem.

Comment: Fair point @Mitch - didn't consider that a primary key might not be a clustered index.

Comment: While SQL Server assigns clustered index to IDENTITY monotonic keys by default, it is occasionally a better design to choose some other column (or combination of columns) as the clustered index.

Answer (score 1):

Joins are faster on integers and less information is sent over networks, so yes there are performance considerations. however depending onthe size of the system, this may not matter much.  It is also generally easier to do ad hoc queries when you don't have to use such a large identifier. If the id is something exposed to the user (person id often is in business applications as name is not unique), then users will definitely prefer to see and use integers. GUIDS though are very necessary if you are doing replication. The real question is why do you want to use the GUID. The answer to that is what will really tell you if yo can substitute with an identity or not.

You should look at using NEWSEQUENTIALID( ) instead of newID(). You also should not let SQL Server put the clustered index on the newId() if you use it or that will cause performance issues. It does this by deafult on the primary key (which I presume this will be) but you can and should change it if you use newid().

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out to NEWSEQUENTIALID. I've been using another algorithm for generating sequential ids I'll consider this one as well.